# How do I access mocha's json report from a script?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Mocha can be [invoked from a script](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-mocha-programmatically) and it has a useful [JSON reporter](http://mochajs.org/#json), but how can one access that reported structure from the invoking script? Redirecting stdout worked:

```js
var Mocha = require('mocha');

var stats = {};
var oldWrite = process.stdout.write;
process.stdout.write = function(txt) {
  stats = JSON.parse(txt).stats; // write invoked in one gulp.
};

new Mocha().
  addFile("test/toyTest").
  reporter("json", {stats: stats}).
  run(function (failures) {
    process.on('exit', function () {
      process.stdout.write = oldWrite;
      console.log("percentage: " + stats.passes/(stats.passes+stats.failures));
      process.exit(failures > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    });
  });
```

but I'd have expected a more direct solution.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the code](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/reporters/json.js#L57), the answer was "you can't":

`process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));`

Since the my solution above is somewhat less than obvious, I created a [pull request](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/pull/2651) to add a reporter option to pass in a target object:

```js
var Mocha = require('mocha');
var report = {};

new Mocha().
  addFile("test/toyTest").
  reporter("json", {"output-object": report}).
  run(function (failures) {
    process.on('exit', function () {
      var s = report.stats;
      console.log("percentage: " + s.passes/(s.passes+s.failures));
      process.exit(failures > 0 ? 1 : 0);
    });
  });
```

which saves capturing process.stdout.write as well as the needless serialization and deserialization of the report structure. I also added a command line to set the output file so you can run:

`mocha -R json --reporter-options output-file=rpt.json`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to create your own reporter like it has been suggested in the [documentation](https://mochajs.org/api/tutorial-custom-reporter.html). I simply copied the json reporter in `node_modules/mocha/lib/reporters/json.js` to new file in my project folder `companyReporter.js` and replaced this line

```
Ln 69: process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
```

With

```
Ln 69: process.send(obj);
```

It was also necessary to update the paths to the requires on line 9 and 10 of `myReporter.js`. I prefer this way because I'm not messing with `process.stdout.write`.

The last change to the code was updating the reporter path:

```
var Mocha = require('mocha');
process.on('message', function (message) {
    const test = message.toString('utf8').replace(/\n$/,'');
    new Mocha().
        addFile(test).
        reporter(__dirname + '/path/to/myReporter.js').
        run(function(failures) {
            process.exit(failures > 0 ? 1 : 0);
        });
});
```